# Conversion from High Res FLAC to 16/44.1 FLAC, keeping all metadata

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, music, flac

I want to convert High resolution flac such as 24 bit 96 Hz and others, to 16 bit 44.1 Hz CD format, while preserving all metadata. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Convert all flac files to format s16 and sampling frequency 44.1 kHz, with extension `.cd.flac`

```
for i in *.flac; do
    ffmpeg -i "$i" \
        -sample_fmt s16 \
        -ar 44100 \
        "$(basename "${i/.flac/}")".cd.flac
done
```

Refer: See a list of audio sample formats (bit depth) with `ffmpeg -sample_fmts`